# get vertex coordinate after transformation OpenGL ES 1.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am working on a board game for android using opengl es 1.0. The game board is a polygon an there are two transformations: scale (zoom) and translate. Now I need the vertex coordinates after the transformation. I managed to get the model view matrix and the projection matrix and now I'm stuck, how do I use this data to get the new coordinates from my old vertex coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new vertex coordinate = projection matrix * modelview matrix * old vertex coordinate